# can ttnavigator render a xib view in objective c?

Tags: three20

I have followed the three20 ttnavigator example in order to make my own app, but I have seen than the view is created in controller, but I would like to make my view in a xib file and then render it from controller when openURLAction is fired, how is it posible?, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used to overwrite the initWithNibName to make my view in a xib file, navigator openURLAction is ok.